# $l^p$ is of first category in $l^q$ if $1 \leq p < q< \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, baire-category

Let $1\leq p<q<+\infty$. Let $B_n=\{⟨x_k\rangle\in l^q: \sum_k |x_k|^p\leq n\}$. Want to show: $B_n$ is closed and nowhere dense in $l^q$. Thus $l^p$ is of first category as a subset of $l^q$.

To show $B_n$ doesn't have interior points seems easy, since you can always construct a sequence of numbers that has arbitrarily small $l^q$-norm but diverges in $l^p$. But how to show it's closed? How to show that the $l^q$-limit of a sequence of elements in $l^p$ is also in $l^p$? I have no idea how to estimate the $l^p$-norm of the limit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partly for notational convenience and also partly to clarify that this isn't something special about $l^p$ and $l^q$, let us identify $l^p$ with $L^p(\mathbb{N},c)$ and $l^q$ with $L^q(\mathbb{N},c)$, where $c$ is the counting measure. For general $(X,\mu)$ we can prove the same statement for $L^p(X,\mu)$ and $L^q(X,\mu)$ as follows.

Let $B_n = \{ x \in L^q : \| x \|_p \leq n \}$. Suppose $x_m$ is a sequence in $B_n$ which converges in the sense of $L^q$ to $x$. To show $B_n$ is closed, it is enough to show that $x \in B_n$. To show $x \in B_n$, we need to show $x \in L^q$ and $\| x \|_p \leq n$. The first part follows because $x$ is the $L^q$ limit of a sequence.

To prove the second part, apply the $L^q$ convergence to extract a subsequence $x_{m_k}$ which converges almost everywhere. Now use Fatou's lemma to get that $\| x \|_p \leq \liminf \| x_{m_k} \|_p \leq n$.

So $x \in B_n$, and so $B_n$ is closed in the sense of $L^q$.

Comment: Why do you need the subsequence $x_{m_k}$ and not just do it with $x_m$?

Comment: @Arnulf Not every sequence which converges in $L^q$ converges a.e. The classic example is the "moving block". It is a bit tedious to write out what that is explicitly, but basically it is a sequence of functions which starts with $1_{[0,1]}$, then indicator functions of the two halves of $[0,1]$, then the three thirds, then the four fourths, etc. This converges in $L^q$ because in the $n$th "stage" it is only nonzero on a set of length $1/n$ and it is bounded. But it does not converge anywhere.

Comment: @Arnulf That said I think this is not the only possible proof, it's just necessary in order to proceed using Fatou's lemma. Another proof would be to use continuity of the norm in a Banach space, which wouldn't need a subsequence because it wouldn't need a.e. convergence. But this is just what I came up with at the time.

Comment: Ok so it's also done with $x_m$ showing that $(L_p(\mu), \|\ \|_p)$ is complete($1\le p<\infty$).

Comment: @Arnulf Well no, that's not really required either, because you're taking it as given that the sequence is convergent, not merely Cauchy. The norm is still continuous in just a normed vector space.

Comment: Ok, so the continuity of $\|\ \|_p$ will do?

Comment: @Arnulf Sure. ${}{}$

Comment: Ok so what do you think about this:
For $n\in\Bbb N$ fixed, taking $\;f\in\bar B_n$ we get that there $\exists\;(f_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}\subset B_n$ s.t. $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k=f$. So by the continuity of $\|\ \|_p$ we get that $\|f\|_p=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|f_k\|_p\le n$, thus $f\in B_n$. And since $\|f-f_k\|_q\to\infty$ it's clear that $f\in L_q(\mu)$. Thereby $\bar B_n=B_n$, i.e. is closed in $L_q(\mu)$.

Answer (score 0):

We first prove that $B_{n}$ is closed.
Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n \in N}$ be a sequence in $B_{n}$,
converges with the limit $x \in l_{q}$ and considering $n=1$ without loss of generality.

For a fixed $n \in N$ and again then for each $i \in N$;
we have,
$\lvert x^{(i)}-x_{n}^{(i)}\rvert\leq \left\|x-x_{n}\right\|_{q} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$,so that $x_{n}^{(i)} \to x^{(i)}$
as $n \to \infty$.But then,
$\sum_{i=1}^{J}\lvert x^{(i)}\rvert^{p}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{J}\lvert x_{n}^{(i)}\rvert^{p} \leq\limsup_{n \to \infty}\left\|x_{n}\right\|_{p}^{p} \leq 1$.
We conclude that $x\in l^{p}$ with $\left\|x\right\|_{p}\leq 1$ and thus $x\in B_{n}$.So $B_{n}$ is closed.

Secondly,
we prove that $B_{n}$ has an empty interior in $l_{q}$.
Pick any $x \in B_{n}$.
We will show that $x$ is not an interior point of $B_{n}$.
We can pick $y\in l^{q} \setminus l^{p}$.
Let $r$>$ 0$ and set ${\overline x}:= \frac{r}{2\left\|y\right\|_{q}}y+x$.
Note that $\overline x \in l_{q}$ as a sum of two elements of $l_{q}$,but $\overline x \not\in l_{p}$.
Indeed,if $\overline x \in l_{p}$,
then also $y=\frac{2 \left\|y \right\|_{q}(\overline x - x)}{r} \in l_{p}$ Contradicting,our fact,$y \not\in l_{p}$.
We conclude that $\overline x \in l_{q} \setminus l_{p}$,where $q>p$.

Note that,
$\left\| \overline x - x\right\|_{q}=\frac{r}{2} $<$r$.
However,
since $\overline x \not\in l_{p}$,
we do not have $x\in B_{n}$.Thus the ball $B(x,r)$ is not contained in $B_{n}$.
As $r>0$ was arbitrary,
we conclude that $x$ is not an interior point of $B_{n}$ and thus $B_{n}$ has an empty interior.
Thus we have shown that $B_{n}$ is a nowhere dense set in $l_{q}$. $l_{p}$ can be expressed as a countable union of nowhere dens sets.Thus $l_{p}$ is of first category in $l_{q}$